SIGSEGV when launching app via Android Studio
For the past many months, I've been getting these aborts on the phone when I try to launch an app via Android Studio. (Note that I am currently running a custom ROM but this was happening under the stock ROM.)
Usually a retry will be successful. Occasionally, it might take two (or three) attempts so the problem is not that serious, just very annoying.
Any and all help gratefully received.
The adb logcat output:
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xd in tid 19481 (ADB-JDWP Connec), pid 19473 (u.id.kmg.xferv2)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Evolution X Version: '9.0'
Build fingerprint: 'google/husky/husky:14/AP1A.240505.005/11677807:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'MP1.0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2024-06-29 06:39:55.119716258+1000
Process uptime: 1s
Cmdline: au.id.kmg.xferv2
pid: 19473, tid: 19481, name: ADB-JDWP Connec  >>> au.id.kmg.xferv2 <<<
uid: 10747
tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001 (PR_TAGGED_ADDR_ENABLE)
pac_enabled_keys: 000000000000000f (PR_PAC_APIAKEY, PR_PAC_APIBKEY, PR_PAC_APDAKEY, PR_PAC_APDBKEY)
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x000000000000000d
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000006dfd62c590  x1  000000000000000b  x2  00000070c740bda0  x3  00000070c740be20
    x4  0000000000001070  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000006dca3f0740  x7  0000006dca3f0630
    x8  167785d0dbb14e34  x9  167785d0dbb14e34  x10 0000006dca3f1c40  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 0000006dfcdfa440  x13 b400006e4ecc4c40  x14 80000001000009f8  x15 b400006e0ecc3d50
    x16 00000070b6ac9328  x17 0000007091779720  x18 0000006cfe27c000  x19 00000070c740be20
    x20 00000070c740bda0  x21 000000000000000b  x22 0000006dfd62c590  x23 00000070b6acb000
    x24 0000006dca3f03b0  x25 0000006dca3f1c00  x26 0000000000000000  x27 00000070b6acba80
    x28 00000070b6aca7f0  x29 00000070c740bc90
    lr  00000070b6ac6b80  sp  00000070c740bb50  pc  0000006dfce4db34  pst 0000000060001000
31 total frames

[snip]

App with package name au.id.kmg.xferv2 is causing the problem. There might be code that tries to use a variable or object that hasn't been initialized properly, resulting in a null pointer dereference. The ROM you're using has issues interacting with the app during launch through Android Studio. If both stock and custom ROMs shows same error log then it suggests the app(au.id.kmg.xferv2) itself might be the culprit. If it becomes a frequent occurrence, it's important to investigate the root cause for a more permanent solution.

It is not that package, it happens with others. But why doesn't a app cause a sigsev?

Can you check if both stock and custom ROMs shows same error log ?

NO - I would have to do a factory reset to go back to the stock ROM!!!!

Everybody: please accept that this has NOTHING to do with that package. This fault happens on MANY packages.
